# How to create a 3D piechart and bar chart in android

Tags: android, charts, 3d, bar-chart, pie-chart

In my android application I need to show a **3D piechart** and **3D barchart**. Does it possible on android.I don't want to show any simple charts.Also is it possible to display the bar charts items in cylindrical shape ?

If possible please help me.

Comment: have u checked this links http://android-coding.blogspot.ae/2011/09/generate-3d-pie-chart-using-google.html and http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/android/index.html

Comment: @Nas Does this need a internet connection.I seen a webservice in first link and i think its used to get the correct piechart by supplying input data.Am i right??

Comment: yes you are right do u have any pblm with this?

Comment: @Nas Sorry we need to display the charts in an offline app.

Comment: @Nas Is there any way to display 3D charts in an offline app.

Comment: @KJEjava48 hi, Have u found any solution for 3D pie chart.